# How to get xml content that is generated by php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, web-scraping

I have and xml url from a supplier which generates xml content dynamically with php like;

```
http://www.example.com/outputxml/index.php?xml_service_id=161
```

This url is valid for a static ip so I gave him my websites hosting ip. Is there a way to open that url in browser with data scraping? Because My internet connection has no static ip.

Thank you.

I have tried  below code;

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/outputxml/index.php?xml_service_id=161?';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

But it gave html format.

Comment: You mean they have ACL ? You can try and proxy that request through your server. Or you can make a web page on your server that will display that.

Comment: Try `echo file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/outputxml/index.php?xml_service_id=161");`

Comment: @frz3993 I have tried this method and it return a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the content on your server with something like a `wget` and then serve it. Please notice that you are probably going to infringe the policy of the xml's author (I don't know the consequences or the policy itself, but you should be careful), so you might consider to at least add a `.htacces` authentication on *your* server's page, just to not make the xml public.

Comment: I have never heard about wget. Does it require function files to upload server? Author of xml is aware of that i will restrict access to the url.

Comment: wget is a common function to download data from a server. It can be called from command line from the server (if you don't want to setup a webserver and you know the xml isn't going to change I suggest to do just that, if you are familiar with `cron` on Linux you can wget the page every now and then). PHP's cURL (which I thought was also called wget) works in a similar way: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I used. It returned html content only.

Comment: Well, html is a subset of xml and it's pretty common for browsers to render the xml as html. Can I have more information about what kind of xml it is?

Comment: I have tried to save the file to the server and it worked.